# Cannot run the coding for VBA GoalSeeker

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Goal Seek()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ResultQty As Integer
    Dim ChangingCell As Integer
    Dim TargetSales As Integer
    
    For i = 4 To 18

        TargetSales = Cells(i,7).value
        Cells(i, 6).Formula = "(C" & i & "*" & "E" & i & ")"
        Set ResultQty = Cells(i,6).value
        Set ChangingCell = Cells(i,3).value
        ResultCell.GoalSeek TargetSales, ChangingCell
    Next i
       
End Sub
```

[image]

I want to get the Qty from goal seeker by setting the targeted sales. But the code shows error. Can anyone help with it?

Comment: "code shows error" is not a very useful description of what exactly happens when you run your code.

Comment: Did you forgot to ser ResultCell?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

'=' missing in formula cell, target cell should not be integer as values are higher than range allowed

```
Sub GoalSeek()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ResultCell As Range
    Dim TargetSales As Variant
    
    For i = 4 To 18
        Set ResultCell = Cells(i, 3)
        TargetSales = Cells(i, 7).Value
        Set ResultCell = Cells(i, 6)
        ResultCell.Formula = "=(C" & i & "*" & "E" & i & ")"
        ResultCell.GoalSeek TargetSales, Range("C" & i)
    Next i
       
End Sub
```